# How can I respawn enemies in Gamemaker Studio 2?

Tags: game-mechanics, game-maker

I know this may have been asked before but I would like an updated answer. So how do I respawn enemies in Gamemaker Studio 2?

Say I have an object called `objBullet` and an enemy `objenemy`; when they collide with each other I want the bullet to destroy the enemy, and the enemy to respawn after a few seconds. As a bonus, if you could tell me how to respawn the enemy in a new random spot that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your enemies are destroyed and don't respawn instantly, you need a different object to spawn them using a timer.

I implemented [this minimal working example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wFJVFG5My1aQZmP930rxwMBJCE7jcQWP/view), in which every time an enemy is destroyed it notifies an object `objSpawnManager`, that will choose a random spot and create a new enemy there.

#### Spawn locations

Every spawn point is identified by an instance of `objSpawn`, and the only thing it does is, well... *exist*. We place as many spawn as we want, because we want to recover their `x` and `y` position when we'll need them later. Spawn locations are stored in a *List* data structure in `objSpawnManager`.

#### Enemy behaviour

When an enemy is hit (I simulated hit with a simple mouse click for simplicity) it destroys itself, then increments the value of variable `queue` of the `objSpawnManager`. This variable tells the `objSpawnManager` how many enemies are waiting for respawn yet.

#### Spawn manager

The object `objSpawnManager` is in charge of the spawning system. Its variable `spawnTime` is the number of seconds for spawning a new enemy; `spawnPoints` is a *DS List* containing all `id`s of `objSpawn` instances.

This is how it works:

- **Step Event**: the manager checks if there are enemies waiting for respawn (`queue>0`); if so, it starts the alarm countdown if it isn't counting down already (`!(alarm[0]>=0)`, "alarm not working").
- **Alarm 0 Event**: get the `id` of a random spawn point from the *DS List*, then create a new enemy at such spawn location, finally decrease the value of `queue`.

And that's it. The rest of the code just sets up some variables, and takes care of freeing memory when objects aren't needed anymore.

Comment: thanks its just what I was trying to do love the example too it really helped me.